# Setup error logging for Kohana

Tags: php, error-handling, kohana, kohana-3

I have exception class:

```
class MartbooksException extends Exception 
{
    public function __construct($msg)
    {
        parent::__construct($msg, 0, null);
        echo $msg;
        Kohana::$log->add(Log::ERROR, $msg);
    }
}
```

> Kohana::$log->add(Log::ERROR, $msg);

Is this all I should do to write logs in application/logs files?

Is this good solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow the Kohana style I would recommend that you use:

```
Class Martbooks_Exception Extends Kohana_Exception
```

as declaration and place the file with name `exception.php` in `classes/martbooks`. This follows the style of Kohana.

Extending `Kohana_Exception` instead of `Exception` allows you to use variable substitution along the lines of

```
throw new Martbooks_Exception ('this is a :v', array (':v' => 'variable', ));
```

As for the defining a `__construct()`-method, the `echo $msg;` part would not be *my* preferred way of solving error handling, any echoing should be done in the block that catches the exception. The same could be argued for in the case of calling `Kohana::$log->add()`, but if you want log every `Martbooks_Exception`, your solution is perfectly valid. In that case I would rewrite your code to:

```
Class Martbooks_Exception Extends Kohana_Exception
{
   public function __construct($message, array $variables = NULL, $code = 0)
   {
     parent::__construct ($message, $variables, $code);
     Kohana::$log->add (Log::ERROR, __ ($message, $variables));
   }
}
```

with a definition of `__construct()` that conforms to `Kohana_Exception`'s `__construct()`.

The only objection that I would have against logging with `Log::ERROR` level in the constructor is that it assumes that every exception is an application level error, which might be true of some exception types, but it could also be used to signal other meanings. The exact meaning of an exception should be left to the exception handling block.

Answer (score 1):

To add a log message all you need is a single line indeed; `Kohana::$log->add($level, $message[, $values])` [see the api](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Kohana_Log)

Besides that, I don't think this is a valid solution. You had better create your own exception handler, as you can see on [this page](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages) of the [userguide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/)